# Corona SDK - display.newtext with options table returns error

Tags: textbox, lua, coronasdk

my code is:

```
local options = 
{
    --parent = textGroup,
    text = "Hello World",     
    x = 100,
    y = 200,
    width = 128,     --required for multi-line and alignment
    font = native.systemFontBold,   
    fontSize = 18,
    align = "right"  --new alignment parameter
}

local test = display.newText(options)
```

But it returns:

```
bad argument #-1 to 'newText' (Proxy expected, got nil)
```

Does anybody know why this happens?

Thank you

Comment: Absolutely no idea, could you try pasting more of the code ? Are you sure that the error happens at this line ?

Comment: This code works fine, maybe in your project you are using different code that you didn't posted here. This error means that options table is nil when you are creating text. Maybe there is some scope issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are using old Corona SDK version which does not have `newText` with options table?

Comment: Error clearly states that there is nil value provided.

Comment: That's it. I downloaded the newest version and it works. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The code that you put it is fine. your error, maybe is on another line. look this post [here](http://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/35570-bad-argument-1-to-addbody-proxy-expected-got-nil/)

it is similar to error that you have. However It is a good information.

I hope that this help you.